# What's considered shaving?

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, sefirat-ha-omer, three-weeks, shaving

During periods of mourning, such as [Sefirat Haomer](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Sefirat_HaOmer#Shaving) and [the three weeks](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Three_Weeks#Shaving) prior to Tisha B'av, shaving is prohibited.

What is considered shaving and what is allowed?

May you pluck out a few hairs here or there?

Can you even out the beard to make it look presentable?

Can you trim nose hairs?

What about shaving the back of your neck?

Comment: Source for your first sentence?